# Magento soap api not working on secure url

Tags: api, soap, wsdl

I have facing issue on `Magento soap api connection whenever try  to use  https  as secure url.`.

My magento  system verson CE 1.7 `and soap version 1.`

System  Url setup is

```
Secure url is  https://www.example.com/
Unsecured  is  http://www.example.com/'
```

When i am changed secure to http://www.example.com/(With out https)

Then the soap client is working properly.

Also,when secure is https://www.example.com ,it
throw below error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://www.example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl' : failed to
>   load external entity
>   "https://www.example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl"

My code is

```
try{

$cli = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl');
$session = $cli->login('marketplace_usr', 'ezvendorplus');
$result = $cli->call($session, 'catalog_product.info', 10887);
var_dump($result);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($e);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is server site issue.Hosting provider is resolved the issue by

```
Step1: add a ssl vhost on private ip for www.example.com 
step2: and reload apache
Step3: and also made a host file entry
```

`Also` if `couldflare  is enable on system` then you need check `cloudeflare setting issue for https`